Why is LiCl a hypovalent covalent molecule?
In a few books and online sources, LiCl is given as an example for "Incomplete Octet of Central Atom" that is, hypovalent. I don't understand why LiCl has covalent properties due to both the reacting atom's small size that favours covalent bonds (this is what I was told) and also why it would form a hypovalent compound.

Whether lithium is "hypovalent" in this and similar compounds is a matter of definition, and at least as I see it the best definition says "no".
Do we include the $2p$ orbitals as valence orbitals or not? If we don't, then lithium can form only one pairwise covalent bond, like hydrogen, and that's what there is in gas-phase forms of $\ce{LiCl, LiH}$ etc (and arguably lithium-bearing molecules in organic chemistry such as organolithium compounds and their pre-workup addition products).
If instead we do accept the $2p$ orbitals as valence orbitals, then the lithium would be hypovalent in all the examples cited above. But the valence-shell $p$ orbitals in alkali metals are so diffuse and high in energy that this does not appear to be a natural choice. Assuming that lithium (and other Group 1 elements including hydrogen) bond through only $s$ orbitals and thus form only one pairwise covalent bond is a more natural and accurate model.
